# Android Studio throws "No signature of method" error, pointing to build.gradle:app

Tags: android, build.gradle

I got this error after trying to run a Kotlin application through Android Studio:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_4blexxmb1pl0fsds689m8rkwz.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_4blexxmb1pl0fsds689m8rkwz$_run_closure1) values: [build_4blexxmb1pl0fsds689m8rkwz$_run_closure1@220b09f3]
```

The error points me to this section of the `build.gradle:app` file (specifically, the line with `android {`):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.bitfighter"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildReleases {
            viewBinding = true
        }
```

What does this error message mean, and what can I change to fix the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to structure the code like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bitfighter"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

The defaultConfig should always only be in the `android` clause and not inside the buildFeatures. Other than that, you don't need a buildReleases clause when you already have added a buildFeatures clause.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Not sure why my code was setup the way it was before.

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I comment this line and its working:

```
buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                useProguard false
                //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
```